# GROUP BY x vs DISTINCT( x )

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

If I have a table with duplicate ids I will get the same result if I use `GROUP BY id` as if I use `SELECT DISTINCT(id)`, right?

So when should I prefer one option over the other?

Comment: There's no need to wrap the columns and/or expressions in parens; the `DISTINCT` keyword applies to the entire SELECT list. The parens around `id` don't influence the query results or the execution plan.

Comment: `group by` is more general. `distinct` is really just a shorthand.  The only time it is really needed is when you do `select distinct *`, because `group by *` isn't allowed.  In other words, focus on learning and using `group by` first.

Comment: ... although `DISTINCT *` would appear to be meaningless. @doub1ejack generally, in the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY should not be used as a substitute for DISTINCT. Under certain circumstances it can produce misleading results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` if you need aggregate functions, like `SUM`, `MAX` etc.

If you only need grouping columns, they are the same (and use the same plan).

Please note that `DISTINCT` is not a function, so this clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), othercol
```

which is the same (except for column order) as

```
SELECT DISTINCT othercol, (id)
```

or just

```
SELECT DISTINCT othercol, id
```

might still give you duplicates on `id` if there are records with same `id` but different `othercol`.

Comment: "might still give you duplicates on id if there are records with same id but different othercol" +1.  `DISTINCT` means that the *row itself* is unique, meaning the combination of all returned columns.

Comment: So my premise, that GROUP BY and DISTINCT return the same result, is not entirely accurate?  If I understand you correctly, DISTINCT returns unique rows, but GROUP BY returns rows ~collapsed by a specific field.  ..though this will frequently look the same when comparing simple queries.  Good to know - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A DISTINCT and GROUP BY usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs. GROUP BY should be used to apply aggregate operators to each group. If all you need is to remove duplicates then use DISTINCT. If you are using sub-queries execution plan for that query varies so in that case you need to check the execution plan before making decision of which is faster.

```
Example of DISTINCT:
 SELECT DISTINCT Employee, Rank
 FROM Employees

Example of GROUP BY:
 SELECT Employee, Rank
 FROM Employees
 GROUP BY Employee, Rank

Example of GROUP BY with aggregate function:
 SELECT Employee, Rank, COUNT(*) EmployeeCount
 FROM Employees
 GROUP BY Employee, Rank
```

Reference : Pinal Dave (http://blog.SQLAuthority.com)

Answer (score 0):

Just extra information:

**It's better to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT if you are querying an indexed field and have a LIMIT, because it would use the index, and not a temporary table**

See these links:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

  "If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created"

---

Example:

```
MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT p.data_prefix FROM my_table p;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range | NULL          | data_prefix | 33      | NULL |   18 | Using index for group-by |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT p.data_prefix FROM my_table p limit 0,40;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range | NULL          | data_prefix | 33      | NULL |   18 | Using index for group-by; Using temporary |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT p.data_prefix FROM my_table p group by p.data_prefix;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range | NULL          | data_prefix | 33      | NULL |   18 | Using index for group-by |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT p.data_prefix FROM my_table p group by p.data_prefix limit 0,40;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range | NULL          | data_prefix | 33      | NULL |   18 | Using index for group-by |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_db]>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of when you might prefer `group by` over a `distinct`. Consider a scenario where a `window function` (**not necessarily row_number()**) needs to be applied on the distinct result set. Respecting the order of operation, you would have to go with something like this using `distinct`

```
select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
from (select distinct id from my_table) t;
```

The same could be achieved without using a subquery using `group by`

```
select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn 
from my_table
group by id;
```

This was possible because `window functions` are applied after `group by` but before `distinct`